# How to check session exists on .aspx file if session created in .php file?

Tags: php, asp.net, .net, session

I am working a php web application project in which all session is created in login.php file and we are also using some .aspx extension .net file in our project.
I want to check my exist session in .aspx extension .net file after creating session in login.php file.

But i don't know that how to write php script in .net file if it is possible.

Please give me solution for checking existence of session on .aspx(.net file). that session has been created on login.php(php file).

Thanks

Comment: You can add an script to php, so .aspx will call script in your php environment via http protocol. Just pass to php scrirpt a session id which is stored in PHPSESSID cookie (or in cookie with name which using in session_name).

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit difficult if you are on a shared hosting. Php stores the sessions as files in its own folder while aspx.net in its own. So here you have two options:

1. Write a C module to combine the folders of both session and also update the session encoding type so that both languages use the same.
2. Second one is easy, use database driven sessions so it will be available to both of the languages.